# How to run an interactive script in CUPS's pipe?

Tags: printing, gui, cups

On our custom system, we run a Windows VM. The task is to print via the system below it (linux), which is responsible for the identity management, such that print jobs can be accounted at the print server. The windows environment shall not know anything specific, hence we use the a generic printer in the win settings. A script should be run somewhere in CUPS, which runs a dialog asking for the identity and offer a choice for the printers. How is this possible?

Comment: That's complicated, and can't work all the time (what if the user running the VM isn't logged in anywhere on the host?)

Comment: This is a precondition. The user has to log in on the host and has to choose which VM should be started.